# date on a variable on angular, typescript and mysql

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

I am starting with Angular and practicing with a form, I try that when entering the record with client, rfc, branch and cost, it sends the current date, I try this way but it does not inject the date into the db, the If you enter other fields, please, I am not yet with the security part, avoid comments that do not contribute and do not add to the solution, as I am telling you, I am starting with Angular, it is not that I am doing wrong, could you please guide me:

this is my component:

```
export class ClientAddEditComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  loading: boolean = false;
  id: number;
  operacion: string = 'Agregar ';
  replace_fec : string = new Date().toISOString();


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private _clientService: ClientService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private aRouter: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      namefact: ['', Validators.required],
      rfcfact: [null, /* [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(13), Validators.minLength(12)] */],
      sucfact: [null, Validators.required],
      pricefact: [null, Validators.required],
    })
    this.id = Number(aRouter.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.replace_fec;
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.id != 0) {
      // Es editar
      this.operacion = 'Editar ';
      this.getClient(this.id);
    }
  }

  getClient(id: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    this._clientService.getClient(id).subscribe((data: Client) => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.form.setValue({
        datesuscribe: data.datesuscribe,
        namefact: data.namefact,
        rfcfact: data.rfcfact,
        sucfact: data.sucfact,
        pricefact: data.pricefact
      })
    })
  }

  addClient() {
    /*  console.log(this.form.value.name);
     console.log(this.form.get('name')?.value); */
     replace_fec : new Date().toISOString();
    const client: Client = {
      datesuscribe: this.replace_fec,
      namefact: this.form.value.namefact,
      rfcfact: this.form.value.rfcfact,
      sucfact: this.form.value.sucfact,
      pricefact: this.form.value.pricefact
    }
    this.loading = true;

    if (this.id !== 0) {
      // its edit 
      client.id = this.id;
      this._clientService.updateClient(this.id, client).subscribe(() => {
        this.toastr.info(`El Cliente ${client.namefact} fue actualizado con exito`, 'Cliente actualizado');
        this.loading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      })

    } else {
      // its add
      this._clientService.saveClient(client).subscribe(() => {
        this.toastr.success(`El Cliente ${client.namefact} fue registrado con exito`, 'Cliente registrado');
        this.loading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

my interface client.ts

```
export interface Client{
    id?: number;
    datesuscribe: string;
    namefact: string; 
    rfcfact: string; 
    sucfact: string; 
    pricefact: Number
}
```

and my service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientService {
  private myAppUrl: string;
  private myApiUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.myAppUrl = environment.endpoint;
    this.myApiUrl = 'api/productos/'
  }

  getClientList(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.http.get<Client[]>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}`);
  }

  deleteClient(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}${id}`)
  }

  saveClient(client: Client): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.post<void>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}`,client)
  }

  getClient(id: number): Observable<Client> {
    return this.http.get<Client>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}${id}`)
  }

  updateClient(id: number, client: Client): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.put<void>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}${id}`, client);
  }
}
```

try to embed it in the variable as if it were a string.

I tried to convert the current date into a string and save it in the replace_fec variable, but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, since it inserts the other fields, but this one doesn't, in the mysql database there is the field as a varchar(50).

Comment: *does not inject the date into the db*, have you checked whether the Angular sends the request with the date field mentioned to your API? You can check with browser DevTools > Network tab > Find the respective request and check the request payload. And also check in your API whether you have received the date, and pass the date to store into DB.

Comment: hello, using postman it doesn't even send me the date field, it only brings me the other fields, the same thing happens on the part of the dev tools, in the console it sends me an ok message but it only inserts or brings the other fields, I don't know if I'm misusing the field in the database or in the component

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      client: '',
      rfc: '',
      branch: '',
      cost: '',
      date: new Date() // Set the current date as the default value
    });
  }

  // Rest of your component code
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this option that you provide me, but it does not bring me the values ​​of the date field and only brings the other fields from the database, using postman the same thing happens, it does not even mark it, in the browser console it does take it but sends it as null, even if I manually add a value to it

Comment: {
        "id": 3,
        "namefact": "c3",
        "rfcfact": "c3",
        "sucfact": "c3",
        "pricefact": 3
    }